# Android HelloGallery Tutorial Trouble

Tags: java, android

First off I am a beginner.

Anyways, so I was trying to play around with the [Hello Gallery tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html). And I'm stuck on step #6. I don't know where the onCreate method ends.

```
`@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGallery.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}'
```

Where do i put this? It just says "Go back to the HelloGallery.java file. After the onCreate(Bundle) method, define the custom ImageAdapter class:"

```
'public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;

    private Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2,
            R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4,
            R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6,
            R.drawable.sample_7
    };

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
        mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mImageIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

        i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

        return i;
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

A method ends after its final `}` brace. Just put the code after the whole block.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ... // stuff you pasted before
}

// put new code here
```

Comment: yeah, sorry this is all new to me. Trying to figure out how to post code like you did. Just a minute.

Comment: you didn't need to post all that code. Just insert the new class right after the `onCreate` method. It will be an inner class of `HelloGallery`.

Comment: Still no luck. Multiple errors. I've try right after the } after onCreate and everywhere else. Everything I need is within the code provided right? If i were to copy and paste in the right places it would work fine, right?

Comment: Yes everything should be in there. If you're struggling with that, you need to read up on Java. You can't expect to get this working if you don't know the class/method/block syntax.